# I need your help with the sentence

Tags: tenses

How are you liking your stay in Berlin? - Is this sentence correct?
or it should be: How do you like your stay in Berlin?

Answer (score 0):

There are two features in the sentence:

First is the use of *how* in the sense not of *by what means/method* but to refer to the quality or extent of the state referred to in the verb.
 - How {ie how well or badly) are you doing/getting on?
 - How are you feeling?

This structure is quite normal colloquial usage.

Second is the use of the continuous present, as opposed to the simple present in the case of the verb *to like*.  Normally for an embedded state, such as liking, the simple present is used.

> I like ice cream.
>   I hate cloves.
>   I love jazz.
>   I detest frogs’ legs.

But, in fact, when the state is seen as in some way part of a present (and temporary) state, the continuous present can be and often is used.  It is no different from saying:

> How are you **enjoying** your stay in Berlin.

The enjoyment will end with the stay.  So will the ‘liking’.  In my British English, it ‘like was not used in this way in my childhood.  But it is now.